# android template merge build.gradle: “apply plugin” added at the botttom

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

I created android template for android studio, 
Focus on merge the **build.gradle (app)** file, I need adding: `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` to project file at the top.

This is my **recipe.xml.ftl**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<recipe>
    <merge from="build.gradle.ftl" to="${escapeXmlAttribute(projectOut)}/build.gradle" />
</recipe>
```

This is my **build.gradle.ftl**

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

dependencies {       
}
```

But after add new code template, my **build.gradle (app)** file become like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.my.full"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

with `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` successfully added at the bottom file.

**How make it added at the top?**

Comment: You need to write your `apply plugin` line at the top of your code.

Comment: just write manually? can't auto when generate from template?

Comment: merge tag only work for xml files while creating android templates